# Largest subset, sum of multiples of each number in array - Timeout error

Tags: algorithm

[image]
My idea of the problem is to find multiples of each number in the array, sum it, and return output

Sample input: numbers: [2,4, 10]
Sample output: 3 7 18

Explanation:
a)

> numbers[0]: 2, is a multiple of 1 and 2. Add 1 and 2. Result 3

b)

> numbers[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eloBm.png): 4, is a multiple of 1,2,4. Add (1+2+4). Result 7

c)

> numbers[2]: 10, is a multiple of 1,2,5,10. Add (1+2+5+10). Result 18

c)

> Output 3 7 18

My current code/algorithm hits into timeout error when the each numbers in the array are huge like 986815066, 100000000.
Is there a particular approach I need to look at? Can I have pseudo understanding of the proposed algorithm?

```
def maxSubsetSum(k):
    summedResult = []
    listOfNumbers = k
    i = 0
    # for number in listOfNumbers:
    while i < len(listOfNumbers):
        commonMultiples = []
        for each in range(1, listOfNumbers[i] + 1):
            if listOfNumbers[i] % each == 0:
                commonMultiples.append(each)
        summedResult.append(sum(commonMultiples))
        i += 1
    return summedResult
```

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000203

Comment: @Dave , If I understood right I need to use sigma function, its formula to identify the sum of divisors of n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each number `x` in the array, you have an `O(x)` operation to find it's factors. The total complexity is basically `O(sum of all elements in the array) = O(k ^ 2)`, which will easily time out.

Optimisation 1:

To find all factors of `n`, you don't need to iterate till `n`. For each `i in range [1, sqrt(n)]`, if `n % i == 0`, add both `i` and `n/i` to the set. This should reduce the [complexity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/422559) to `O(k ^ 3/2)`.

Optimisation 2:

As a pre-computation step, use Sieve of Eratosthenes to find the prime factorisation for all numbers. Then use [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sum-factors-number/) formula to find the sum of all factors. The prime factorisation for `n` can be done in a `O(log n)`, so this approach should definitely pass all test cases.

(I haven't added any "details" per se, that's for you to figure out. These pointers should help you arrive at the solution.)

Comment: On optimization 1, why the range is until sqrt(n). And, we won't be able to use float value in the range right?

Comment: @RajeshMappu consider two factors such that `x * y = n`. Now, if both are greater than `sqrt(n)`, then `x * y > n`, which is incorrect. Thus one factor must be less than `sqrt(n)`.

Comment: Utilized optimization 2 step and made my way from there. Thanks! @Abhinav Mathur